# how to solve "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "sqlite3.Cursor") to str"

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I'm trying to make my home page display a user's username after they login. I kept getting this error first,

```
 sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 14 supplied.
```

I stopped receiving this error after I changed `(self.current)` to `(self.current,)`.
However, I'm now receiving this error,

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "sqlite3.Cursor") to str
```

I tried to solve this by making user a string `"Olá " + str(user)`
This only displayed `Olá <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000219024FA650>`.

**main.py**

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    usr = ObjectProperty()
    email = ObjectProperty()
    current = ""

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        user = cur.execute('SELECT user FROM id WHERE email =?', (self.current,))
        self.usr.text = "Olá " + user
        print("Olá " + user)

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty()
    password = ObjectProperty()

    def verify_user(self):

        cur.execute('SELECT * from id WHERE email="%s" AND password="%s"' % (self.email.text, self.password.text))
        if cur.fetchone() is not None:
            HomeScreen.current = self.email.text
            sm.current = 'Casa'
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.invalidLogin()
            self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""

    def invalidLogin(self):
        pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                  content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),separator_color=(1.36, 0, .27, 1))
        pop.open()
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""

kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

sm = ScreenManagement()

screens = [LoginScreen(name="login"), SignUpScreen(name="signup"),HomeScreen(name="Casa"),SearchScreen(name="Search")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = 'login'

con = sql.connect('userlog.db')
cur = con.cursor()

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
HomeScreen>:
    name: "Casa"
    usr: usr
    email: email

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'images/LightBackgroundReOr.png'

    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .1

        Image:
            id: imageView
            source: 'images/uaiLogoReOr.png'
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.7}

        Label:
            id: usr
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Olá "

        Label:
            id: email
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: ""

...
```

Comment: Go through the tutorial again. `x = cursor.execute(query)` is not what they tell you to do.

Comment: You don't even have to assign the result of `cur.execute()` to anything, it simply modifies the cursor object. But you *can* assign it to something, like you did to `user`, which is then just a reference to the `cur` object. Next, `"Olá " + user` is trying to add a cursor object onto the end of a string - that won't work of course and causes the error.

Comment: Why is there a special character in Olá . Did you check after removing this . Can you also print the type of string Olá ,so that we will know both the string are of same stype.

Comment: @Grismar So how would I make user equal to the user in the sql table if I can't do ```user = cur.execute()```?

Comment: By using `cur.fetchone()` for example, which you would know if you'd taken the trouble of just reading the basic documentation of the functions you're using. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute